# Passing arguments with spaces to python script in VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to pass two arguments to a python script in VBA and run it.

The arguments are the workbook_folder and workbook_name, both of them contain spaces.

The code below passes only the workbook_folder argument up to the first space to the python script and it does not pass the workbook_name argument.

I have tried a few things but I cannot find a way to make it work.

```vb
Dim workbook_folder As String
Dim workbook_name As String

workbook_folder = Application.ThisWorkbook.path
workbook_name = Application.ThisWorkbook.Name


Dim shell As Object
Dim exePath, scriptPath As String

Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

exePath = """<fpth of python exe>"""
scriptPath = "<fpth of python script"

shell.Run exePath & " " & scriptPath & " " & workbook_folder & " " & workbook_name
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```vb
> shell.Run exePath & " " & scriptPath & " " & workbook_folder & " " & workbook_name
> ```

That instruction is doing too many things, and that's making your code harder to debug than it needs to be.

Introduce a variable.

```vb
Dim shellCommand As String
shellCommand = exePath & " " & scriptPath & " " & workbook_folder & " " & workbook_name

Debug.Print shellCommand
Stop ' validate the string in the immediate pane, tweak double quotes, fix, F5 to resume execution

shell.Run shellCommand
```

Comment: I changed it as you suggested and tried different combinations of double-triple quotes but I cannot make it work yet.

Comment: @svzap do you know what output string you want to achieve? Try running the command in cmd.exe

Comment: Yes, I want to get the full path of the workbook. But right now I am getting the workbook path up to the first space in the path, the rest of the path after the space is not returned. I used to have <"cmd /k" & " " &> before the <exePath>  as shellCommand, then I removed it, but I was having the same problem with and without it.

Comment: What I mean is, write the actual shell command in the actual command-line interface, so you know what you want the string to look like. *Then* make your VBA code generate that exact same string. If you don't know what the CLI syntax is, then this isn't a VBA question.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the syntax and I solved it as follow:

```
Dim workbook_folder As String
Dim workbook_name As String

workbook_folder = Application.ThisWorkbook.path
workbook_name = Application.ThisWorkbook.Name


Dim shell As Object
Dim exePath, scriptPath As String

Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

exePath = """<fpth of python exe>"""
scriptPath = "<fpth of python script"

Dim shellCommand As String
shellCommand = exePath & " " & scriptPath & " " & """" & workbook_folder & """" & " " & """" & workbook_name & """"

shell.Run shellCommand
```

Thanks for your help Mathieu!